# Python Linear Programming Constraints using Cplex

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex

```
C:\Users\Zayad\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:/Users/Zayad/Desktop/Courses/Optimization II/Python/mod1 (1).py"
```

inconsistent arguments

Process finished with **exit code 0**

I don't know why I get the below error please help

```
C:\Users\Zayad\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:/Users/Zayad/Desktop/Courses/Optimization II/Python/mod1 (1).py"
```

inconsistent arguments

Process finished with **exit code 0**

Another Question what does cplex.SparsePair do if there is an example that would be great

Thanks

Comment: C:\Users\Zayad\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:/Users/Zayad/Desktop/Courses/Optimization II/Python/mod1 (1).py"
inconsistent arguments

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score -1):

See [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._matrices.SparsePair-class.html)

And you may find an example foodmanu.py at `CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\examples\src\python`

You'll see

```
ic_dict["lin_expr"] = cplex.SparsePair(ind=[varindex(m, p, USE)], val=[1.0])
```

NB: There is a much easier python API: [docplex](https://pypi.org/project/docplex/)